# How to encrypt a password traveling across TCP?

Tags: ios, encryption, cryptography, app-store

In my game app, running from iPhone/iPad to a central server that I control via TCP, I need to send login information.

What I currently do is send a LOGIN opcode with ascii bytes for login and password in the clear.  I don't want to send user's passwords in the clear - they could be on a wifi connection for example.

How can I handle encryption of this?  Here are my requirements:

- I don't *want* to use a 3rd party lib, I will if absolutely necessary.  If necessary it has to be BSD license or similar
- What's the impact of me answering "yes" on "does your App have cryptography in it" to the App store

  - I want this app to be available in every country
- Is it acceptable to, locally on the device, hash the password, and send that cached value only? The user's account could be compromised by the hash being stolen, but the password wouldn't be lost (and I wouldn't be storing their passwords)..
- I can't have some kind of OAuth out-of-the-app setup system done as I've experienced before, it's too invasive

I'm sort of at a loss here.  I appreciate any good help here as this is one of the last 3 things I need to address before ending almost a year of development.. (so this isn't theoretical or premature optimizing! it has grown in to an actual issue..)

Comment: Have you looked into a type of Public Key Encryption like [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA)? Or, if you're comfortable keeping the master key in the client, what about [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)? Pre-built libraries exist, but you can implement these methods yourself - their specifications are public domain.

Comment: Secure transport layer or not, there's never any need to store clear-text passwords, or send them over the wire. Do some reading. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the obligatory: "Don't invent your own password scheme.  If you aren't an expert, you will do it wrong.  If you are an expert, you will do it wrong in a creative way that is horribly broken but which brokenness will be invisible until your scheme is in use by thousands"

Next, be clear about what you want to protect, and why.  You mention plaintext user passwords being bad for some reason.  Are you concerned that a password the user uses in a bunch of places will be leaked by your application, compromising the user's other accounts, or are you more concerned that the attacker will be able to gain access to your user's account?

My concern with what I read in the subtext of your hashing idea is that the hash that the client sends will never change (unless the password changes).  This makes it a plaintext-equivalent for authentication (the attacker need only steal the hash; they can then authenticate without knowing the password).  It also makes the password a little more vulnerable to brute-force attacks by someone who can see the hash.

I get the impression that you want to avoid encryption for concerns that it will limit the availability of your application.  I can understand that reason.

Let's assume that a cryptographically secure hash isn't cryptography (and I don't know if it is or not, but it isn't in terms of U.S. export restrictions as far as I have read).  My suggestion would be a very simple challenge-response protocol to use to verify that the user has the password (I recommend you look up "challenge-response protocol" online).

One caveat here is that I don't address getting the password to the server in the first place; just the server verifying that the user has the correct password for the account.  Think of this as a general idea of how you might prevent things like replay attacks, and make life more difficult for attackers that can see the data stream:

Client: "I wish to authenticate as John Smith"

Server: "Okay 'John Smith'-claiming-person, take the current date and time (2011-09-09@12:04:33AM) and a random number I just thought up: 4bazillion, and hash them with your password.  Let me know what you got."

Client:

- prompts user for password
- hashes
- Says: "I got: gaAGRtcq4qt22332."

Server:

- takes date and time and random number and hashes with password
- compares data from client with calculated data
- If there is a match:

  - Says:  "Okay, you're in."
- Otherwise:

  - Says:  "Go pound sand."

Comment: A version of this, relating to your first paragraph: [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_remote_password_protocol)

Comment: Hi, good comments and thank you!  I actually have considered the method you describe, and understand the replay attacks issue. In fact I use this for another different portion of my protocol.  But I do not see a way to first get the password to the server without doing something I don't really want to - The closest to best thing I could do here would on account creation be to open some https on the side, make the account with password, and then log in with my protocol.  Solves it but kind of sucks

Answer (score 2):

TLS/SSL. Just use it. It is built into iOS.

As for encryption, yes, you will need to claim you use encryption, which will require you to get an (easy) online registration certificate from the government.

Comment: What about the server - which isn't iOS obviously (it's FreeBSD) - what APIs on iOS should I use and what library should I use on the server, and what is the concept here - server generates a certificate for every connection?

Comment: Raw Library: OpenSSL, PolarSSL, etc. Pre-canned: Apache with mod_ssl

Comment: Do you really have to say it uses encryption if it only uses the TLS libraries built into iOS?

Comment: @Nick: Yes. Its spelled out in Apple's documentation as well.

Comment: As a side not here, I spent quite a while trying to first use libssh2 and then OpenSSL.  libssh2 doesn't really support the use case, but the API is usable.  OpenSSL's API is totally awful.  And the latency and renegotiation and everything is completely unsuitable for my environment.  Thanks for the suggestion though.  What I need is a small portion of MY protocol to be encrypted stream, not an encrypted stream and (basically) managed connection to stuff my protocol in to.  I wasn't clear though

Answer (score 2):

Authenticate with your service over HTTPs. You will not need to use any third party libraries. You can implement this as either a post or a get.